# jQuery code works for console but not in-page

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, forms

I have a form element defined as:

```
<div class="field">
    <div class="name">
        <label for="User_LastName">
            Last name: <span class="asterisk">*</span></label>
    </div>
    <div class="value">
        <%= Html.TextBox("User.LastName", Model.LastName)%>
        <%= Html.ValidationMessage("User.LastName")%>
    </div>
</div>
```

and a jQuery selector that is supposed to detect when the input gets focus and highlight the parent:

```
    $("input").focus(function() {
    //watching for an event where an input form comes into focus
        $(this).parent().addClass("curFocus").children("div").toggle();
    });
```

If i paste this code into firebug's console - things work as planned. However, i'm running this from a 'RenderPartial' .net mvc page. Other jQuery code sitting within the same      $(document).ready(function() { block work correctly.

The form uses html helpers to generate the inputs which might complicate the process somewhat - but even so... i'm seeing correct behavior when that code's in console but not in a 'real-time' page.

How do i troubleshoot this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you're rendering a partial, the `$("input")` selector doesn't find the element to rig this up to, because it isn't there yet.  If you change it to a live event, it'll work on elements added after `document.ready` executes.

To fix it, use [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) like this:

```
$("input").live('focus', function() {
  $(this).parent().addClass("curFocus").children("div").toggle();
});
```

Note: requires jQuery **1.4.1+**

Comment: RenderPartial happens server side, so all the inputs should be there when `$(document).ready()` fires.

Comment: @Charlino - Not if he's loading it via ajax, which is usually the case, at least in most stuff I see or do :)

Answer (score 0):

**Use setTimeOut**

```
  setOut(function(){
        $("input").focus(function() {
             //watching for an event where an input form comes into focus
             $(this).parent().addClass("curFocus").children("div").toggle();
        });
  },500)
```